# Apache Spark writer partitionBy causes OOM

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, partitioning, large-data

A dataset of Parquet files with a size of more than 700gb is available. The Parquet consists of 2 columns, each with a JSON document.
I would now like to convert these Parquet files and save them with partitions. Read, transform and save. Finally, there is a new folder with partitions and corresponding Parquet files. So much for the idea.

Reading the source data is done with a ***spark.read.parquet("/my/folder/ **/*.parquet")***.
The transformation is done on this dataframe with some JSON auxiliary methods. After completion, a dataframe with several columns is available. In addition to a date (YYYY-MM-DD), there are other columns, and the original data is also still available.
For writing, I execute a **partitionByRange("date", "col1", "col2")**, **sortWithinPartitions("date", "col1")** and a **write.partititionBy("date")**.
My small Spark cluster (6 workers, with 4 core and 2GB ram) are now busy for a few hours. When writing, however, there is always an oom. My driver (spark-shell) is equipped with 24gb ram and the machine does not give more.
The files individually can be processed well, my problem seems to be the amount of data. My guess: Merging the partial results from the workers leads to an oom in the driver. I have also experimented with the maxRecordsPerFile option, unfortunately without success.
What other possibilities are there to avoid oom?

```
archiveDF
  .repartitionByRange($"xxxx", $"startTime",$"uuid") // !!! causes oom !!!
  .sortWithinPartitions("xxxx","startTime")
  .write
  .mode("append")
  .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 50000)
  .partitionBy("xxxx")
  .format("parquet")
  .save("/long-term-archive/data-store")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use repartitionByRange (in Spark 3.2.1 anyway) without supplying a number of wanted partitions, spark uses `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (which is 200 by default) as the number of partitions you want to end up with.

If you divide your total data by the nr of partitions, you get 700 GB/200 partitions = 3.5 GB/partition. This is very large (typically around 100MB partitions are a good idea) and your executors have only 0.5GB RAM/core. So in your case, you could try to use 7000 partitions and see if you get a better result like that. Something like:

```
.repartitionByRange(7000, $"xxxx", $"startTime",$"uuid")
```

I'm assuming there is no huge data skew on those repartitioning keys. If there is a large skew, you want have to salt your keys.

Another question: what is the use of repartitioning again when writing? Repartitioning requires a shuffle operation which is typically one of the more expensive operations there are. You should try to aim to repartition the least amount of times.

Comment: The spark.read.parquet(...) creates about 6.500 partitions. Assuming 700gb divided by 128mb results in 5.400 partitions. In this way, I tried the repartitionByRange with values 9.000 and 18.000. But there is no difference.

When removing the partitionByRange the above code succeeds. Not sure, but probably the dataframe has storage level MEMORY_ONLY. It could be an option to try persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY) ... unfortunately by filesystem is zfs and deleting files is an expensive operation. Here, spark gets timeouts and run into other trouble.

Comment: If `spark.read.parquet()` creates about 6500 partitions, that means that the parquet file you're reading has 6500 partitions. That would still mean that when doing `.repartitionByRange` without supplying an integer would result in 200 partitions. But since youve tried 9000 and 18000 too, it seems like you're suffering from data skew. 

Do you know what the data is partitioned by when reading it in? Maybe you can keep the partitioning! If not, you can try salting: https://towardsdatascience.com/skewed-data-in-spark-add-salt-to-compensate-16d44404088b?gi=3a3825902668